# DAX—LASTNONBLANK returns blank for string

Tags: string, powerbi, dax

fairly new to DAX and Power BI. I am having trouble making the LASTNONBLANK function consistent when applied to strings. I have two tables that look like the following:

[image]

I am trying to calculate the 'Category' column in Table 2 with the LASTNONBLANK function so that it returns the correct Category from Table 1. Since there are multiple entries for the same SKU, I am trying to use this function to select a single string. And yes, there are situations where the Category may be different for the same SKU, in which case the LASTNONBLANK function selects what I want correctly (i.e. reverse alphabetical).

I am currently using the following function:

```
Category = CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(Table1[Category],0))
```

This function works, but not for all entries in Table 2. I apply it to the entire column, and about a third of the entries populate correctly. The rest all appear to be blank. I've checked the successful vs unsuccessful entries by SKU in Table 1, and I cannot see a difference.

Any thoughts on the issue?

Comment: Is there a relationship between these tables? I also suggest you include sample data (not an image) that also includes one of these differences in category per SKU and another table of your expected output. Perhaps `LASTNONBLANK` is a bit silly to use since it's a time intelligence function primarily.

Comment: I can't share the actual data unfortunately. I am sorry since I realize that makes it harder to answer the question. One thought based on your comment: If LASTNONBLANK may not be appropriate here, are there any other functions that come to mind that can select a min or a max string value from a column for multiple entries?